# JSONP Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, callback, jsonp

I need to call from a wordpress page, the content that I can edit in wp-admin on that page.
It's a page, and not a post.

Can anyone provide me with the code that I need to access the WP JSON API?
It needs to be JSONP as the call is made from a HTML hosted on another server.
I found this WP plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Thanks in advance!

Andrei

Comment: What did you try? People here are willing to help, but pointing to a site and asking others to do research on a specific product to be able to help is probably not the best use of their time.

Answer (score 3):

According to that API, you specify `get_page` and the page id, like so:

```
var page_id = 11111;

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.org/?json=get_page&page_id='+page_id+'&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
               alert("Title of page retrieved: "+data.page.title);
               console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

Comment: mccannf thank you so much for your answer! the only problem is that will pop-up a message with the 'Tittle of page retrieved: TrafficVoice' and that's it. There is no loading of the page content in there :(

Comment: it's DONE! mccannf, God bless you, or whatever God you believe in or not... I've searched in other tutorials that I have used and didn't work, lol, and based on what you typed there at alert, I've added:             $("#content").html(data.page.content); and it's works! THANK YOU SO MUCH! For two weeks I tried to get this work. THANK YOU!

Comment: I cannot vote as I don't have 15 reputation, but as soon as I will have it, I'll come back and +1 the answer :)

Comment: mccannf, there's a problem: after compiling the HTML + CSS + JS files on phonegap, the script won't work. Nothing is showing up. Have any idea why?

Comment: Don't know much about phonegap, sorry. Are you using JQuery Mobile? Have a look at this article: http://richdotnet.blogspot.ie/2012/07/cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-phonegap.html?m=1

Comment: The problem is Android. Not the app itself or phonegap, as it won't load the content if I try the mobile version of the template hosted on a webserver. SO, what is it with Android that doesn't like in that code? OR what does it need more?

Comment: I recommend a new question showing your code that works on a PC and not on Android. Tag it as Android and see who answers.